# Restore-AzSqlDatabase FromGeoBackup to a different subscription and region

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

We have a set of azure production databases that we need to plan disaster recovery for.  This means we need to be able to prove that should our primary Azure region fail, we need to prove that we can use Azure sql backups to restore into an alternative subscription into a different region.

I have checked that Get-AzSqlDatabaseGeoBackup returns an valid object for all the databases.  However, i would now like to use Restore-AzSqlDatabase -FromGeoBackup options to restore a database to a different region in another subscription.

I don't think i can use this command, because the options don't exist to do it.  Am i correct?

If i can't use that command, how can i restore Azure sql backups to a different region and subscription (hopefully using powershell so that we can automate it)?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**You can use both PowerShell and azure portal for restore and Backups**

> **Perform a geo-restore operation using Azure Portal.**

***Log in to the Azure portal -> Browse the Azure SQL Server -> Create a SQL database -> Select a backup -> Browse the database -> Click OK***

[image: reference 1]

> **Perform a geo-restore operation using Powershell**

1. Log in to the portal
2. Open the CloudShell PowerShell console
3. List the subscription. If your account has multiple subscriptions, then list the intended subscription where you have the database
4. Set the subscription Id using ***Get-AzSubscription*** output piped to ***Set-AzContext***.
5. Get the geo-backups details into the variable ***$geobackups*** for the specified database SSISDB
6. Prepare the restore by listing the target resource group name, target server and target database and

   ```
   Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
   ```
7. In this case, the SSISDB restored to the target Azure SQL database.

   ```
   $resourceGroupName= 'xxxxx'
   $ServerName='xxxxx'
   $TargetResourceGroup='xxxxx'
   $TargetServer='azuresqlxxxx'
   $TargetDatabaseName='SSISDB_Target'
   $GeoBackups = Get-AzSqlDatabaseGeoBackup -ResourceGroupName 
   $resourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName
   $GeoBackups | Where-Object {$_.DatabaseName -eq "SSISDB"}
   ($GeoBackups | Where-Object {$_.DatabaseName -eq "SSISDB"}).ResourceId
   Restore-AzSqlDatabase -FromGeoBackup -ResourceGroupName 
   $TargetResourceGroup -ServerName $TargetServer -TargetDatabaseName 
   $TargetDatabaseName -ResourceId ($GeoBackups | Where-Object 
   {$_.DatabaseName -eq "SSISDB"}).ResourceId
   ```

Please refer this [link](https://www.sqlshack.com/quick-start-guide-to-geo-restore-in-azure-sql-database/) for more information

Comment: thanks for this BhanunagasaiVamsi-MT.  Regarding the powershell approach, are two Set-AzContext statements possible?  I.e. one at the start to get the geo-backup from subscription1 and another just before the Restore-AzSqlDatabase in order to set the subscription to subscription2 (i.e. the target server will be in a different subscription and region?).  It's not clear whether this is possible from your code example.  Thanks

Comment: In fact when i run Set-AzContext just before the restore statement, i receive the following error: Restore-AzSqlDatabase : The provided subscription 'Subscription1Guid' did not match the subscription in the Url 'subscription2guid'.  The values in quotes are subscription guids